# Trying to toggle one div at a time and hide all others as button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is the HTML divs that I am toggling. They contain iframes and that is essentially what I am showing and not showing based on which buttons I click.

```
<div class="iframe_div" id="lowerDIV" style="display: none;">
  <iframe width="100%" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V4H3SRnkf94" frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>

  <button class="close_iframe_inside" onclick="closeiFrameInner()">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
  </button>
  <span class="close_iframe_inside_text">Close video</span>
</div>

<div class="iframe_div" id="lowerDIV2" style="display: none;">
  <iframe width="100%" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YrbSK9HG8w" frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>

  <button class="close_iframe_inside" onclick="closeiFrameInner()">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
  </button>
  <span class="close_iframe_inside_text">Close video</span>
</div>
```

Here are the buttons in my Html. I am trying to set it up where when I click one button, the associated iframe pops up and all other iframes are toggled hidden.

```
<div class="icon-bar">
  <ul class="sidebarIcons">
    <li>
      <button onclick="showonlyone()" style="width: 62px;">
        <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
        <span class="tooltipText">Video solution</span>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button onclick="showonlyone()" style="width: 62px;">
        <i class="fa fa-percent"></i>
        <span class="tooltipText">Helpful formulas</span>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using one function to do the toggle, at least add something to the function or element to distinguish the target, for example adding the target ID

```js
function showonlyone(targetId){
   $('#'+targetId).show(); // show only the element with id=targetId
   $('#'+targetId).siblings().hide(); // hide everything else of the same level as target
}
```

then in your html

```html
<div class="icon-bar">
  <ul class="sidebarIcons">
    <li>
      <button onclick="showonlyone('lowerDIV')" style="width: 62px;">
        <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
        <span class="tooltipText">Video solution</span>
      </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button onclick="showonlyone('lowerDIV2')" style="width: 62px;">
        <i class="fa fa-percent"></i>
        <span class="tooltipText">Helpful formulas</span>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I implemented your code and nothing is happening when clicking the buttons

Comment: @FrostedFlakes333 first you have to wrap your list of lowerDIV under 1 parent. checkout this https://jsfiddle.net/sanusi87/5048kpxy/2/

Comment: Since the buttons are display on the right side of the container in a vertical fashion and the iframes will pop up else where, does it matter that they are under 1 parent?

Comment: I tried adding this to my code and I lost all of the styling for my buttons

Comment: If you are using my function, yes, need to be under 1 parent.... siblings() method means select any other children, except the selected... For the button, you can use your own button, just need to set the click function correctly

Comment: This is all my code together, including yours. The styling for the buttons are gone im trying to get the jquery to scroll into view where the iframes should be appearing. Sorry for the crazy questions, I am just a total newbie. Here is my fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/5suzdar0/

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a parent Div

```js
const parentDiv = document.getElementById('parent-div')
const btAB = document.getElementById('bt-ab')

btAB.onclick=()=>
  {
  btAB.textContent = (parentDiv.classList.toggle('Show-B'))
                    ? 'show A'
                    : 'show B'
  }
```

```css
#parent-div #div-a { display: block; }
#parent-div #div-b { display: none; }

#parent-div.Show-B #div-a { display: none; }
#parent-div.Show-B #div-b { display: block; }
```

```html
<button id="bt-ab">show B</button>

<div id="parent-div" class="">
  <div id="div-a">AAAAA</div>
  <div id="div-b">BBBBB</div>
</div>
```

If you have more than 2 elements to show / hide use:

```js
const parentDiv = document.getElementById('parent-div')
const btAB = document.getElementById('bt-ab')

const listABCD = ['Show-A','Show-B','Show-C','Show-D']
const nextABCD = ['Show B','Show C','Show D','Show A']
var   itemABCD = 0

btAB.onclick=()=>
  {
  parentDiv.classList.remove(listABCD[itemABCD])
  itemABCD = ++itemABCD % listABCD.length
  parentDiv.classList.add(listABCD[itemABCD])
  btAB.textContent = nextABCD[itemABCD]
  }
```

```css
#parent-div > div { display: none; }

#parent-div.Show-A #div-a { display: block; }
#parent-div.Show-B #div-b { display: block; }
#parent-div.Show-C #div-c { display: block; }
#parent-div.Show-D #div-d { display: block; }
```

```html
<button id="bt-ab">Show B</button>

<div id="parent-div" class="Show-A">
  <div id="div-a">AAAAA</div>
  <div id="div-b">BBBBB</div>
  <div id="div-c">CCCCC</div>
  <div id="div-d">DDDDD</div>
</div>
```